# Find which program is associated with notification permissions

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have a program masquerading as Edge pushing notifications to my desktop. I'd like to get rid of it, but all I get is the fake name "Microsoft Edge". How can I find what programs are associated with a given notification permission?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this notification.  I suspect that Edge, actually is the program sending the notifications, but it's a website that is responsible.  How you handle problem that is extremely easy, but useless, if your original diagnostic is actually accurate.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a program masquerading as Edge pushing notifications to my
> desktop

Run a full (not quick) scan with Windows Defender.

Then when done go to Defender options and run an Offline Scan. This will restart your computer so make sure everything is closed.

When done restart and test.

The object is to get rid of the program and identifying it is not completely necessary.

Comment: Well, I'll let you know how it goes in 16 hours